# Compiler can't resolve modules

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 with Web Essentials latest version.

At the moment typescript is giving me a hard time as AMD compiling does not seem to be reliable. Most of the time intellisense is happy with the module path (not always) but the compiler never accepts it.

This is what my file structure looks like:

```
-scripts
  -app
    -controls
      FeedbackControl.ts
    -models
      FeedbackModel.ts
```

---

FeedbackControl.ts

```
import model = require("../models/feedbackmodel");
export class FeedbackControl{
    constructor(){}
}
```

---

FeedbackModel.ts

```
export class FeedbackModel{
  constructor(){}
}
```

---

This looks valid to me and even the IDE is ok with it. But when I try to compile this is what the compiler thinks:

**Build: Unable to resolve external module '"../models/feedbackmodel"'.**

On a side node:
Now and then the IDE is showing me such errors, too. A restart of visual studio helps. What always leads to an error is when I do not use lower case characters in module path only. Like so:

```
import model = require("../models/FeedbackModel");
```

I have no idea what I need to do to get this fixed. My team mates are having this issue, too, so I guess there is something wrong with the solution. As a workaround we disabled typescript compiling on each .ts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string casing of the `import` statement i.e. `/models/FeedbackModel` needs to match the case used in the file system.

Comment: Then it does work with the compiler indeed. Thank you. But how do I get intellisense to work? `/models/FeedbackModel` makes the compiler happy but there is also a curly red line marking my import statement. And of course each reference to that module is marked as an error `Could not find symbol 'module'`

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer are you using resharper by any chance? disable it and restart visual studio

Comment: Thank you @basarat. Disabling Resharper would have been out of question.However, i fixed the problem by recreating the files that couldn´t be resolved. So it seems that there was something wrong with some of the .ts files. It is not the content because I copied the content of the old files into the new files. So I guess it was something in the header.

Comment: I had a similar problem where many of my types were marked as error but  on hover over with the mouse you could see VS could resolve them. I cleared the Resharper cache and that fixed the problem.